# How to display group SL number in group header section on Crystal Report

Tags: header, crystal-reports, numbers, record, group

I have a report where I need to add a serial number for Group Title.

I require to generate this number in the report; let us consider it as Group Number (as we do Row Number in the detail section)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a built-in function that returns the current group's number. So you could just create a formula field with it:

```
GroupNumber
```

and place the formula field in your group header.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have already solved this issue in this way. :)